# Fastest possible way to iterate through a specific list?

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list:

```
list=['plu;ean;price;quantity','plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1']
```

I want to iterate over the list + split the list by ";" and put an if clause, like this:

```
for item in list:
    split_item=item.split(";")
    if split_item[0] == "string_value" or split_item[1] == "string_value":
        do something.....
```

I was wondering, if this is the fastest way possible? Let's say my initial list is a lot bigger (has a lot more list items). I tried with list comprehensions:

```
item=[item.split(";") for item in list if item.split(";")[0] == "string_value" or item.split(";")[1] == "string_value"]
```

But this is actually giving me slower results. The first case is giving me an average of 90ms, while the second one is giving me an average of 130ms.
Am I doing the list comprehension wrong? Is there a faster solution?

Comment: In the first case you call `item.split(";")` once. In the second case, you call `item.split(";")` 3 times. The second case is bound to be slower.

Comment: Aside: if you're processing tabular data, it might be worthwhile looking into a library like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).  When/if you can vectorize operations you can get significant performance benefits over pure Python loops, although of course that depends entirely on the parts of the problem you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: It turns out that the Regex cache was being a bit unfair to the competition. My bad. Regex is only a small percentage faster.

If you're looking for speed, hcwhsa's answer should be good enough. If you need slightly more, look to `re`.

```
import re
from itertools import chain

lis = ['plu;ean;price;quantity'*1000, 'plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'*100]*1000

matcher = re.compile('^(?:plu(?:;|$)|[^;]*;ean(?:;|$))').match
[l.split(';') for l in lis if matcher(l)]
```

Timings, for mostly positive results (aka. `split` is the major cause of slowness):

```
SETUP="
import re
from itertools import chain
matcher = re.compile('^(?:plu(?:;|$)|[^;]*;ean(?:;|$))').match

lis = ['plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'+chr(i) for i in range(10000)] + ['plu;ean;price;quantity' for i in range(10000)]
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[[x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== 'plu' or y=='ean']"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[l.split(';') for l in lis if matcher(l)]"
```

We see mine's a little faster.

```
10 loops, best of 3: 55 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 49.5 msec per loop
```

For mostly negative results (most things are filtered):

```
SETUP="
import re
from itertools import chain
matcher = re.compile('^(?:plu(?:;|$)|[^;]*;ean(?:;|$))').match

lis = ['plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'+chr(i) for i in range(1000)] + ['plu;ean;price;quantity' for i in range(10000)]
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[[x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== 'plu' or y=='ean']"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[l.split(';') for l in lis if matcher(l)]"
```

The lead's a *touch* higher.

```
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 35.7 msec per loop
```

---

If the result will always be unique, use

```
next([x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== 'plu' or y=='ean')
```

or the faster Regex version

```
next(filter(matcher, lis)).split(';')
```

(use `itertools.ifilter` on Python 2).

Timings:

```
SETUP="
import re
from itertools import chain
matcher = re.compile('^(?:plu(?:;|$)|[^;]*;ean(?:;|$))').match

lis = ['plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'+chr(i) for i in range(10000)] + ['plu;ean;price;quantity'] + ['plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'+chr(i) for i in range(10000)]
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[[x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== 'plu' or y=='ean']"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "next([x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== 'plu' or y=='ean')"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[l.split(';') for l in lis if matcher(l)]"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "next(filter(matcher, lis)).split(';')"
```

Results:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 31.3 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 msec per loop
```

So this gives a substantial boost to both methods.

Comment: Wow, regex is not my stronger side, but this downed it to 40ms. Since in my case, all but 1 thing is filtered, this is by far the best solution

Comment: Am I right in thinking you un-accepted this? If so, why? Also, I have a new method that should be much faster for unique solutions, both with and without Regex.

Comment: Turns out the Regex cache was being unfair. Either way you might want to re-look at the last part of my answer.

Comment: Hey mate, i have no idea why this got unaccepted. Maybe i did it by mistake. Your solution is by far the best for me. Since i am doing port of my code to Windows mobile device (with PyCe port of python 2.5), thats the reason why i need performance :). Thanks once again.

Comment: Since itertools is not included in python 2.5, i used this which gives me best results so far: `[next(l.split(';') for l in list if matcher(l))]`. I tried multiple solutions found on stackoverflow, but this is currently giving me best results.

Comment: This is still performing abit slow on mobile device (640mhz ARM cpu :(), but waay faster than before. Is it possible to perform faster looping/finding of data on some other data structure than list? I didn't find this...

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering, if this is the fastest way possible?

No, of course not. You can implement it a lot faster in hand-coded assembly than in Python. So what?

If the "do something..." is not trivial, and there are many matches, the cost to do something 100000 times is going to be a lot more expensive than the cost of looping 500000 times, so finding the fastest way to loop doesn't matter at all.

In fact, just calling `split` two to three each loop instead of remembering and reusing the result is going to swamp the cost of iteration, and not passing a maxsplit argument when you only care about two results may as well.

---

So, you're trying to optimize the wrong thing. But what if, after you fix everything else, it turns out that the cost of iteration really does matter here?

Well, you can't use a comprehension directly to speed things up, because comprehensions are for expressions that return values, not statements to do things.

But, if you look at your code, you'll realize you're actually doing three things: splitting each string, then filtering out the ones that don't match, then doing the "do something". So, you can use a comprehension for the first two parts, and then you're only using a slow `for` loop for the much smaller list of values that passed the filter.

It looks like you tried this, but you made two mistakes.

First, you're better off with a generator expression than a list comprehension—you don't need a list here, just something to iterator over, so don't pay to build one.

Second, you don't want to `split` the string three times. You can probably find some convoluted way to get the `split` done once in a single comprehension, but why bother? Just write each step as its own step.

So:

```
split_items = (item.split(';') for item in items)
filtered_items = (item for item in split_items 
                  if item[0] == "string_value" or item[1] == "string_value")
for item in filtered_items:
    do something...
```

Will this actually be faster? If you can get some real test data, and "do something..." code, that shows that the iteration is a bottleneck, you can test on that real data and code. Until then, there's nothing to test.

Comment: filtered_items = (item for item in split_items if item[0] == "string_value" or item[1] == "string_value")

Comment: It gives the same results as the first case of mine, but you opened my eyes:)

Comment: @sale1902: Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

Split the whole string only when the first two items retrieved from `str.split(';', 2)` satisfy the conditions:

```
>>> strs = 'plu;ean;price;quantity'
>>> strs.split(';', 2)
['plu', 'ean', 'price;quantity']
```

Here split the third item(`'price;quantity'`) only if the first two items have satisfied the condition:

```
>>> lis = ['plu;ean;price;quantity'*1000, 'plu1;ean1;price1;quantity1'*1000]*1000
```

Normal for-loop, single split of whole string for each item of the list.

```
>>> %%timeit
for item in lis:
    split_item=item.split(";")
    if split_item[0] == "plu" or split_item[1] == "ean":pass
... 
1 loops, best of 3: 952 ms per loop
```

List comprehension equivalent to the for-loop above:

```
>>> %timeit [x for x in (item.split(';') for item in lis) if x[0]== "plu" or x[1]=="ean"]
1 loops, best of 3: 961 ms per loop
```

Split on-demand:

```
>>> %timeit [[x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (item.split(';', 2) for item in lis) if x== "plu" or y=="ean"]
1 loops, best of 3: 508 ms per loop
```

Of course, if the list and strings are small then such optimisation doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree that this is the issue here: not splitting all the list if you only need the first two elements.

Comment: The advantage here is wholly dependent on the *mix*.  If it is "almost always" the case that the if-condition succeeds, you should just do the complete split; if the if-condition "almost never" succeeds, then you should first split off the first two elements and test them.  Where the cross-over occurs depends on things like the average length of the list and how long a partial split takes compared to a full split.

Comment: This is the best solution, atleast for my case, it lowered to 80ms on my test list. Since my result (from the if conditional) will always be unique, this is the best solution in that case for now.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good alternative here.

You can use a combination of map and filter. Try this:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>splited_list = itertools.imap(lambda x: x.split(";"), your_list)
>>>result = filter(lambda x: filter(lambda x: x[0] == "plu" or x[1] == "string_value", lista)
```

The first item will create a iterator of elements. And The second one will filter it.
I run a small benchmark in my IPython Notebook shell, and got the following results:

1st test:

[image]

With small sizes, the one-line solution works better

2nd test:

[image]

With a bigger list, the map/filter solution is slightly better

3rd test:

[image]

With a big list and bigger elements, the map/filter solution it`s way better.

I guess the difference in performance continues increasing as the size of the list goes by, untill peaks in 66% more time (in a 10000 elements list trial).

The difference between the map/filter solution and the list comprehension solutions is the number of calls to .split(). Ones calls it 3 times for each item, the other just one, because list comprehensions are just a pythonic way to do map/filter together. I used to use list comprehensions a lot, and thought that i don't knew what the lambda was all about. Untill i discovered that map and list comprehensions are the same thing.

If you don't care about memory usage, you can use regular map instead of imap. It will create the list with splits at once. It will use more memory to store it, but its slightly faster.

Actually, if you don't care about memory usage, you can write the map/filter solution using 2 list comprehensions, and get the same exact result. Checkout:

[image]

Comment: `imap` and `ifilter` do the same thing as generator expressions, except that they take a _function_ rather than an expression. And likewise for `map` and `filter` vs. list comprehensions. If your expression was just 'call this function", that's not a problem; in fact, it's a benefit. But if your expression was `x[0] == "plu" or x[1] == "string_value"`, wrapping that in a function slows things down (because that's an extra function call each time through the loop), and also makes things less readable (because that `lambda x:` just gets in the way).

Comment: But you can definitely balance between lazy (`imap`/`ifilter`/genexpr) and strict (`map`/`filter`/listcomp). If you're filtering to keep M values out of N, the wasted cost of M list-building steps in the strict variants may easily be canceled out by the benefit of not having to go through N iterator-protocol steps in the lazy ones, so `filter` or a listcomp will often win if M << N.

Comment: Finally, be very careful with the testing. If your last step is just building a genexpr/imap/ifilter and you never iterate it, you haven't done anything yet! Make sure to loop over it (or, for as little test overhead as possible, feed it to a `collections.deque(max_len=0)`) inside your `timeit`.

Comment: But i pass the imap generator to the filter. It is enough to iterate through the entire generator, isnt?

Comment: Yes, as long as the last step is strict, everything's fine. And I didn't assume you just got that right by accident; I figured it was intention, but wanted to make it clear for other readers (especially those who are used to Python 3, where `map` and `filter` are lazy).